# How to Retweet my Main twitter acc using Twython?

Tags: python, twython

I created another twitter acc to help promote my main, so I was wondering how do you retweet ones account using *twython* are there any examples?

I found a few but I'm still a little confused? thanks!

What I am trying is:

```
user_timeline=twitter.getUserTimeline(sreen_name="slaughdaradio", count = 100,)
```

to tweet in user_timeline:

```
print tweet ['text']
```

It keeps giving me a syntax error for 'tweet'.

Comment: ive tried this which i searched on internet

Comment: user_timeline=twitter.getUserTimeline(sreen_name="slaughdaradio", count = 100,)
for tweet in user_timeline:
    print tweet ['text']

Comment: user_timeline=twitter.getUserTimeline(sreen_name="slaughdaradio", count = 100,)
 for tweet in user_timeline:
     print tweet ['text']

Comment: it keeps giving me an synax error for 'tweet'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print tweet ['text']
```

change to

```
print(tweet ['text'])
```

I'm assume your python version is Python3.  In Python3, `print` have changed to `print()`.